# Fill column of a dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill a column of a dataframe from another dataframe based on conditions. Let's say my first dataframe is df1 and the second is named df2.

```
# df1 is described as bellow :
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|   A  |  1   |
|   B  |  2   |
|   C  |  3   |
|   A  |  1   |
+------+------+
```

And

```
# df2 is described as bellow :
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|   A  |  NaN |
|   B  |  NaN |
|   D  |  NaN |
+------+------+
```

Each distinct value of Col1 has her an id number (In Col2), so what I want is to fill the NaN values in df2.Col2 where df2.Col1==df1.Col1 .
So that my second dataframe will look like :

```
# df2 :
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|   A  |  1   |
|   B  |  2   |
|   D  |  NaN |
+------+------+
```

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: have a look at numpy.where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df2.set_index('Col1').combine_first(df1.drop_duplicates().set_index('Col1')).reset_index()
```

If need check dupes only in `id` column:

```
df = df2.set_index('Col1').combine_first(df1.drop_duplicates().set_index('Col1')).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with the filter `df1.Col1 == df2.Col1`

```
df2['Col2'] = df1[df1.Col1 == df2.Col1]['Col2']
```

It is even better to use `loc` (but less clear from my point of view)

```
df2['Col2'] = df1.loc[df1.Col1 == df2.Col2, 'Col2']
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but il returns : ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: ok, you have twice A in column 1. Use `df1.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` first.

Comment: Note that if you have 2 different lines like "A 1" and "A 2", drop duplicate will not removes one and you will still have the ValueError which is a good think since it cannot know which line to use.